# $http post request doesn't work and sends an "Possible unhandled rejection" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am using angular to send a post request to a backend made with Symphony, with data coming from an HTML form. The problem is that it doesn't work at all, and it sends me a possible unhandled rejection error in the browser console. When I use the REST client of my browser it works fine. Here are some pieces of code:

Here is the HTML:

```
<header>
    <div id="categorymenu">
        <nav class="subnav">
            <a href="#!welcome" class="logo pull-left">
                <img style="height:50%;  /* width: 70%; */ max-width: 100%;" title="Simplepxcreate" alt="Simplepxcreate" src="images/logo.png">
            </a>

            <ul class="nav-pills categorymenu container" style="color: #254F97 !important">
                <li> 
                    <a class="{{menActive1}} home" href="#!welcome" style="box-shadow: #CCC 1.5px 1.5px 0px 0px;">
                        <i class="icon-home icon-white font18"></i> 
                        <span> Accueil</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="{{menActive2}}" href="#!catalogue/all/all" style="box-shadow: #CCC 1.5px 1.5px 0px 0px;">
                        <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> 
                        Produits
                    </a>
                    <div style="border-radius: 0px; box-shadow: #254F9766 1.5px 1.5px 0px 0px;">
                        <div class="loader" ng-show="loader1" style="margin-left: 50%"></div>
                        <ul >
                            <li ng-repeat="cathegorie in Acccathegories" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; border-bottom-style: dotted;">
                                <a href="#!catalogue/{{cathegorie.category.id}}/all">
                                    <i class="icon-cogs"></i>
                                    {{cathegorie.category.name}}
                                </a> 
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- 
                       Debut 
                        Ceci n'est pas utilisé voila pour quoi il ne s'affiche pas :  
                    -->
                    <div style="display: none; /*width:1000px;*/">
                        <!--
                            <ul>
                                <li class="categorymenu" ng-repeat="cathegorie in finalCathegories"><a href="#!catalogue/{{cathegorie.id}}/all">{{cathegorie.name}}</a> 
                                    <ul class="nav-pills" ng.if="cathegorie.subs!='nosubs'">
                                        <li ng-repeat="sub in cathegorie.subs"><a href="#!catalogue/{{cathegorie.id}}/{{sub.id}}">{{sub.name}}</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        -->
                        <div class="loader" ng-show="loader1" style="/*margin-left: 50%/*"></div> 

                        <div>
                            <ul style="/*margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;*/" style=" /*display: block; width: 1000px;*/">
                                <div style="padding: 15px; border-bottom: dotted;/*float: left; width: 25%; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 5px;*/ /*float: left; width: 400px; margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 20px;*/" ng-repeat="cathegorie in Acccathegories">
                                    <li style="">
                                        <a href="#!catalogue/{{cathegorie.category.id}}/all" style=" background-color: #254F97; color: #FFF; padding: 5px; /*color: #254F97;*/ text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 14px; " id="mycats"  >
                                            <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> 
                                            <img ng-if="!showSubs" src="images/repair-tools.png"  style="width: 20px; height: 20px; margin-right: 10px; display: none;" >
                                            {{cathegorie.category.name}}
                                        </a> 
                                        <ul style="/*margin-left: 30px;*/ ">
                                            <li ng-repeat=" sub in cathegorie.subs">
                                                <a id="mysubs" href="#!catalogue/{{sub.id}}/all">{{sub.name}}<span></span></a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <ul>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- 
                        Fin 
                    -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="{{menActive3}}" href="#!nosservices" style="box-shadow: #CCC 1.5px 1.5px 0px 0px;">
                        <i class="icon-cogs"></i> 
                        Services
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="{{menActive4}}" href="#!devis/all" style="box-shadow: #CCC 1.5px 1.5px 0px 0px;">
                        <i class="icon-check"></i> 
                        Devis
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="{{menActive5}}" href="#!contact" style="box-shadow: #CCC 1.5px 1.5px 0px 0px;">
                        <i class="icon-envelope"></i> 
                        Nous contacter
                    </a> 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

<div id="maincontainer">

  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <!--  breadcrumb --> 
      <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
          <span class="divider">/</span>
        </li>
        <li class="active">Devis</li>
      </ul>  

      <div class="row mt40">
        <div class="span8">
          <h2 class="heading2">
            <span> 
              <i class="icon-phone"></i> 
              Demandez un devis
            </span>
          </h2>
          <form class="form-vertical contactform"  method="post" name="devis">
            <div class="control-group">
              <label for="name" class="control-label">
                Name 
                <span class="required">*</span>
              </label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text"  placeholder="Votre nom et prénom ou celui de votre société" class="required" id="name" value="" name="name" ng-model="devis.nom" style="width: 80%; border-radius: inherit;">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <label for="email" class="control-label">
                Email 
                <span class="required">*</span>
              </label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Votre adresse mail" class="required email" id="email" value="" ng-model="devis.email" style="width: 80%; border-radius: inherit;">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <label for="url" class="control-label">
                Telephone
              </label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Votre numéro de téléphone" value="" name="url" ng-model="devis.telephone" style="width: 80%; border-radius: inherit;">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <label for="url" class="control-label">
                Objet
              </label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Objet de votre devis" id="name" value="" name="url" ng-model="devis.objet" style="width: 80%; border-radius: inherit;">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <label for="url" class="control-label">
                Service : 
              </label>
              <div class="controls">
                <select id="select" style="width: 80%; border-radius: inherit;" ng-model="devis.service">
                  <option ng-repeat="service in Accservices" value="{{service.name}}"  ng-selected="choosen.name=service.name">
                    {{service.name}}
                  </option> 
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <label for="message" class="control-label">
                Message
              </label>
              <div class="controls">
                <textarea placeholder="Décrivez votre besoin ici" class="required" rows="6" cols="40" id="message" ng-model="devis.message" style="width: 80%; border-radius: inherit;"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-actions">
              <input class="btn" type="reset" value="Annuler" ng-click="abort()">
              <input class="btn btn-orange pull-right" type="submit" value="Envoyer" id="submit_id" style="margin-right: 20px" ng-click="askDevis(devis)">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

        <!-- Sidebar Start-->
        <div class="span4">
          <aside>
            <div class="sidewidt">
              <h2 class="heading2">
                <span> 
                  <i class="icon-envelope"></i> 
                  Nos coordonnées
                </span>
              </h2>
              <p> 
                Horraires:<br>
                Lundi-Vendrdi: 08h-19h<br>
                Samedi: 08h-15h<br>
                <br>
                <i class="icon-phone"></i>  
                Phone: (237) 33 40 53 50<br>
                <i class="icon-envelope"></i> 
                Email: infos@auto-22.com / client@auto-22.com<br>
                <i class="icon-globe"></i> 
                Web: Auto22.com<br>
              </p>
            </div>
          </aside>
        </div>
        <!-- Sidebar End-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer id="footer">
    <section class="footersocial">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3 info">
                    <h2> <i class="icon-link"></i> LA propos </h2>
                   <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Qui sommes-nous</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="">Notre mission</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="">Notre équipe</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="span3 contact">
                    <h2> <i class="icon-phone-sign"></i> Contact </h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="location"> Douala, Cameroun.‎</li>
                        <li class="phone"> Phone: (237) 33 40 53 50</li>
                        <li class="mobile"> Email: infos@auto-22.com / client@auto-22.com</li>
                        <li class="email"> Web: Auto22.com</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="span3 twitter">
                    <h2>  Temoignages </h2> 
                    <div class="flexslider" id="testimonialsidebar">
                        <ul class="slides">
                            <li ng-repeat="temoignage in Temoignages">{{temoignage.content}} <br>
                                <span class="pull-right orange">By : {{temoignage.nameby}}</span> </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span3 facebook">
                    <h2> Newsletter </h2>
                    <section id="newslettersignup">
                        <div class="pull-left mt20">
                            <form class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="input-prepend">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="votre mail ici" id="inputIcon" class="span2">
                                    <input value="Souscrire" class="btn btn-orange" type="submit">
                                    Envoyer </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </section>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="copyrightbottom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span5 social">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="span2 textcenter"> Auto22 @ 2017 powered by Njangihost </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <a id="gotop" href="#">Back to top</a> 
</footer>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#categorymenu').stickThis();
    }); 
</script>
```

And here is the controller and the service:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('Auto22', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
  .when('/welcome', {
    templateUrl : 'views/welcome.html',
    controller: 'welcomeCtrl'
  })
  .when('/catalogue/:name/:subname', {
    templateUrl : 'views/catalogue.html',
    controller: 'catalogueCtrl'
  })
  .when('/services/:servicename', {
    templateUrl : 'views/services.html',
    controller: 'servicesCtrl'
  })
  .when('/nosservices', {
    templateUrl : 'views/nosServices.html',
    controller: 'nosservicesCtrl'
  })
  .when('/produit/:idproduct', {
    templateUrl: 'views/produit.html',
    controller: 'produitCtrl'
  })
  .when('/devis/:servicename', {
    templateUrl: 'views/devis.html',
    controller: 'devisCtrl'
  })
  .when('/contact', {
    templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
    controller: 'contactCtrl'
  })
  .when('/promotion', {
    templateUrl : 'views/promotion.html',
    controller: 'promotionCtrl'
  })
  .when('/resultats/:produit', {
    templateUrl : 'views/resultats.html',
    controller: 'resultatsCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/welcome'
    });
})
.config(function($sceProvider) {
    $sceProvider.enabled(false);
})
.controller('devisCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal, cathegorie, devis, temoignages, subCathegorie, $rootScope, services, $routeParams){
  document.title="Devis";
  $scope.menActive1="";
  $scope.menActive2="";
  $scope.menActive3="";
  $scope.menActive4="active";
  $scope.menActive5="";
  $scope.loader1=true;
  $rootScope.apiAddress2="http://www.auto22industry.com/auto22new/manager/web/api/corporate";
  $rootScope.apiAddress="http://www.auto22industry.com/auto22new/manager/web/api/catalog";
  $rootScope.apiAddress3="http://www.auto22industry.com/auto22new/manager/web/api";
  $scope.choosen={};
  services.listservices().then(function(allServices){
    $scope.Accservices=[];
    $scope.Accservices=allServices.data;
    for(var i=0; i<=$scope.Accservices.length; i++){
      if($routeParams.servicename==$scope.Accservices[i].id){
        $scope.choosen=$scope.Accservices[i];
        break;
      };
    }; 
    console.log($scope.choosen.name);
  });

  /*List all the cathegories and their subcathegories*/
  subCathegorie.listSubCathegorie().then(function(subcathegories){
    $scope.Acccathegories=[];
    if(subcathegories.data){$scope.loader1=false;}
    $scope.Acccathegories=subcathegories.data;
    console.log($scope.Acccathegories);
  });
  $scope.messages={};

  $scope.askDevis = function(Devis){
    console.log("In the ask devis function");
    /*for(var monService in $scope.Accservices){
      console.log("In the for loop");
      console.log(Devis.service);
      console.log(Devis.nom);
      console.log($scope.Accservices[monService].name);
      if(Devis.service == $scope.Accservices[monService].name){
        $scope.askedService = $scope.Accservices[monService];
        console.log($scope.askedService);
        break;
      };
    };*/

    devis.sendDevisRequest(Devis.nom, Devis.email, Devis.telephone, Devis.objet, Devis.service, Devis.message).then(function(validation){
      $scope.messages=validation;
      console.log($scope.messages);
    });

    if($scope.messages){
      console.log('opening pop up');
      var $uibModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'Popup.html',
      controller: 'PopupCont'
      });
    }else{
      console.log('opening pop up');
      var $uibModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'PopupErr.html',
      controller: 'PopupCont'
      });
    }
  };

  temoignages.listalltemoignages().then(function(allTemoignages){
    $scope.Temoignages=[];
    $scope.Temoignages=allTemoignages.data.data;
  });

})
.controller('PopupCont', function($scope, $uibModalInstance){
  $scope.close = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('');
  };
})
.service('devis', function($http, $rootScope){
  var validation={};

  this.sendDevisRequest = function(nom, email, telephone, objet, service, description) {
    var req = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: $rootScope.apiAddress + '/devis/create',
      data: {
        "name": nom,
        "email": email,
        "phone": telephone,
        "object": objet,
        "service": service,
        "description": description
      }
    }

    return $http(req).then(function(response){
      validation=response;
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in the service just return the http instead of catching the promise.Catch it in the controller.

```
.service('devis', function($http, $rootScope){
  var validation={};

  this.sendDevisRequest = function(nom, email, telephone, objet, service, description) {
    var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: $rootScope.apiAddress + '/devis/create',
 data: {
  "name": nom,
  "email": email,
  "phone": telephone,
  "object": objet,
  "service": service,
  "description": description
  }
}
    return $http(req) 
  }
});
```

also data comes under `data` property in the promise

```
devis.sendDevisRequest(Devis.nom, Devis.email, Devis.telephone, Devis.objet, Devis.service, Devis.message).then(function(validation){

    $scope.messages=validation.data; // data property
    console.log($scope.messages);

})
```

Comment: I've applied your solution but doesn't seems to work